# Accessing GRASS modules through python IDE

Tags: python, ide, open-source, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to access GRASS modules and functions from within a python IDE. (I am using WingIDE)

My googling search tells me it can be done (i think) but I cant find any clear instructions on how to do it. Is anyone able to give me some clear instructions on what I need to do?

Simply typing this line of code does not work. I dont think it is locating the grass modules. I have arcgis 10.1

```
import sys
import grass.script as grass
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to use both the argis toolbox and GRASS tools.

Anyway hopefully it is something easy and obvious to someone out there,

Any help would be great,

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: so what exactly are you asking? Is your program not importing `grass.script` properly when it runs? Are you trying to get code intelligence to work? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Wing IDE may be picking up another Python installation as the default, rather than the one where you have grass installed.  You can check that in Show Python Environment in the Source menu, and configure it in Project Properties in the Project menu (or Configure Python dialog in Wing 101).  If for some reason you didn't install grass into Python but have it in a separate place, you may need to configure Python Path as well or instead.

Once that's done, the script should be able to run in the debugger and successfully import the module (or you can also do this in the Python Shell).

If this doesn't help please let me know or email support@wingware.com.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond @Wingware's important point, and presuming that your "grass.script" is a python module, your PYTHONPATH needs to include the directory that contains "grass.script" for the python interpreter to be able to find/import the desired script. You should be able to set this via the IDE or from the OS prior to starting the IDE.